# In Google Scholar, is it possible to view the list of papers cited by a specific paper?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

For any paper on Google Scholar, you can click "Cited by ..." to see a list of subsequent papers that cite the original paper.

However, is it possible to see a list of papers that the original paper cites? I realize that one can simply view the paper itself for the list of references, but I would like a way to see it as a list of links in Google Scholar, similar to the "Cited by ..." list.

Comment: Maybe this could be a more general question: even beyond Google Scholar, is there a good source for this information that does not require you to have access to the paper?

Comment: In some cases, Google Scholar gives you a link to a website that has a list of the referenced papers: the journal's website or an online repository like IEEEexplore.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Scopus can do this. Unfortunately I don't have access to it at my university.

Answer (score 8):

As you mentioned, unfortunately, Google Scholar only provides the list of publications that cite a given reference.

However, if you have access to [Web of Science](https://webofknowledge.com), to look up a list of references cited in a given publication, you can use the *Cited References* tool.

Note that some journals are not indexed by Web of Science, so having several tools to do the job may be the best way to approach this; e.g., in addition to Web of Science, you could also use Research Gate as mentioned in the other answer. For those journals that *are* indexed by Web of Science, I find the *Cited References* tool to be very useful.

Answer (score 5):

No, Google Scholar does not do this.  If you want the content of the paper you are going to need to access the paper.  I would suggest you find the paper on [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/home), where many of the references are active links.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Microsoft is no longer providing the Microsoft Academic (Ended in December of 2021).

Google Scholar might not give you this option but your problem might be solved by [Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com). In Microsoft Academic, there is a tab that shows the references in a very simple manner.